# Are all materials that have 0 electrical resistance superconductors?

Tags: electrical-resistance, definition, superconductivity

Are all materials that have 0 electrical resistance [superconductors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superconductivity)?

Are all perfect diamagnets superconductors？

Comment: The surface of a [topological insulator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_insulator) can have zero resistance for some modes of electrical conduction but is not a superconductor in the usual sense. The comments in this [reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/askscience/comments/3g50ug/whats_the_difference_between_a_superconductor_and/) provide a good starting point for understanding the distinction.